# How do i pretty print javascript objects/variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

**** NOT A DUPE *** The duplicate referenced answer refers to JSON only ****

I am looking to avoid this when logging js vars to the console:

```
var user = {
  first: 'Jack',
  last: 'Green',
  age: 54
};
 
// plain console log
console.log(user);
 
// or with interpolation:
console.log(`User: ${user}`);
```

This ends up like:

```
{ prop1: 'value1', prop2: 2 }
 
User: [Object object]
```

Comment: Log the variable itself rather than a `.toString()` version of the variable as in `console.log('User: ', user);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the above example to:

```
var user = {
  first: 'Jack',
  last: 'Green',
  age: 54
};

// plain console log
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2));

// or with interpolation:
console.log(`User: ${JSON.stringify(user, undefined, 2)}`);
```

and now we get the nice looking output:

```
{
  "first": "Jack",
  "last": "Green",
  "age": 54
}

User: {
  "first": "Jack",
  "last": "Green",
  "age": 54
}
```

Comment: That's not pretty. There's no need for quotes around keys. Please, an answer that doesn't use JSON.

Comment: Huh looks good to me- thanks for the advice - you're a true genius and obviously bored.